# Extract URL form downloaded html files with rvest using for loop

Tags: r, rvest

I have downloaded 258 .html files in a folder and I want to extract URLs out of them. Each file contains about 15 URLs that I want to extract.

I have a line of code that extracts the links on an individual level, but I can't figure out how to write a loop for all 258 files. If I run the loop below, than R creats a character vector of only 258.

```
#this works for a single file:
html_out <- read_html(files_list[1])

links_out <- html_nodes(html_out, xpath = "//*[@class='content-teaser__blocklink']") %>% html_attr("href")
links_out


#this doesn't work:
for (i in 1:length(files_list)) {
  html_out <- read_html(files_list[i])
  links_out[i] <- html_nodes(html_out, xpath = "//*[@class='content-teaser__blocklink']") %>% html_attr("href")

}
```

Comment: Don't have anything to test this but try using `links_out[[i]]` in the `for` loop.

Comment: What is class(links_out)? A reproducible example would help

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I figured it out using your ideas. links_out is a charachter(). I now changed it into a list, than the double brackets links_out[[i]] worked.